# awesome nested set where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using `awesome_nested_set` and I have implement this code in my active admin code

```
f.input :parent, :as => :select, :collection => f.template.nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i| "#{'--' * i.level} #{i.name}" }
```

I want implement where condition in this code, How can do this?